# Java MethodHandle api seems to produce incorrect type

Tags: java, methodhandle

Given this code:

```
MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(void.class, DomainObject.class);
NOOP_METHOD = RULE_METHOD_LOOKUP.findVirtual(RulesEngine.class, "noOpRule", mt);
```

the NOOP_METHOD produced is

```
MethodHandle(RulesEngine,DomainObject)void
```

Why is that first parameter there, that causes failures when i invoke it, like

```
mh.invoke(domainObject);
```

as the error message is:

```
 java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: cannot convert MethodHandle(RulesEngine,DomainObject)void to (DomainObject)void
```

Here is the method in question:

```
public void noOpRule(DomainObject d) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `noOpRule` is an instance method of the `RulesEngine` class.

To call it in regular code, you need a `RulesEnigne` object as well as a `DomainObject` object:

```
public static void callNoOpRule(RulesEngine rulesEngine, DomainObject domainObject) {
    rulesEngine.noOpRule(domainObject);
}
```

To call it through the `MethodHandle` you need both objects as well:

```
mh.invoke(rulesEngine, domainObject);
```

or, if you are trying to invoking from an instance method of `RulesEngine`:

```
mh.invoke(this, domainObject);
```

Comment: thanks. i realized after what a stupid question on my part. but thanks very much for the answer.